# MFRC522 and Bluetooth not work together

Tags: bluetooth, qt, rfid, raspberry-pi-desktop, bluez

I have a program in which I use pyqt5, MFRC522 and bluetooth. I have 3 threads, one for the interface, one for the MFRC522 and one for the bluetooth. If I run the MFRC522 and the bluetooth separately they work fine, but if I run both at the same time only the bluetooth works and the MFRC522 stops reading the rfid.

The MFRC522 library used is here https://github.com/pimylifeup/MFRC522-python

Why can't work together? MFRC522 and Bluetooth

This is the code:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal
import sys
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QStackedWidget, QWidget

import time
import bluetooth import *

from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522

class ThreadBluetooth(QThread):
    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def recv_timeout(self, timeout=0.3):
        self.sock.setblocking(0)
        total_data = []
        data = ''
        begin = time.time()
        begin2 = time.time()
        while 1:
            if time.time() - begin2 > 1:
                break
            if total_data and time.time() - begin > timeout:
                break
            elif time.time() - begin > timeout * 2:
                break
            try:
                data = self.sock.recv(8192)

                if data:
                    total_data.append(data)
                    begin = time.time()
                else:
                    time.sleep(0.1)
            except:
                pass
        return b''.join(total_data).decode()  # ''.join(total_data)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            bd_addr = "98:D3:D2:72:8B:43"
            port = 1
            self.sock = BluetoothSocket(RFCOMM)
            self.bluetoothConnecting = True
            try:
                self.sock.connect((bd_addr, port))
                while self.bluetoothConnecting:
                    self.verifyConnection()
                    data = self.recv_timeout()
            except Exception as e:
                self.sock.close()
                time.sleep(10)

    def verifyConnection(self):
        try:
            self.sock.getpeername()
            self.bluetoothConnecting = True
        except:
            self.bluetoothConnecting = False
            self.sock.close()


class RFID (QThread):
    signal = pyqtSignal(str)
    delay = 2

    # terminandoTurno = False

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.readCard()

    def readCard(self):
        try:
            reader = SimpleMFRC522()
            while True:
                codeRFID, text = reader.read()
                self.signal.emit(codeRFID)
                time.sleep(self.delay)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)



class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.central_widget = QStackedWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 100, 800, 480)
        home = Home(self)
        self.central_widget.addWidget(home)


class Home(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Home, self).__init__(parent)
        uic.loadUi("UI/MainQWidget.ui", self)
        self.initBluetooth()
        self.initRFID()

    def initBluetooth(self):
        self.threadBluetooth = ThreadBluetooth()
        self.threadBluetooth.start()

    def initRFID(self):
        self.RFID = RFID()
        self.RFID.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Maybe the library you are using isn't thread save. Are you sure it is?

Comment: @jsotola Why can't work together? MFRC522 and Bluetooth

Comment: add that question to your post ... as it stands now, it still has no question